# Misplaced Automatic in output of ContourPlot3D

Tags: plotting, warning-messages

The following gives an error when displayed in the front end:

```
cp = ContourPlot3D[x, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, Contours -> {{0.}}]
```

[image]

There is an extraneous `Automatic` in the directives/primitives of the `GraphicsComplex` of the output:

```
Short[cp[[1, 2, 1]], 3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The command so simple, it must be a bug.  Is there a workaround?  (Using an explicit `ContourStyle` does not fix it.)

Version/system: V10.2, Mac OSX.

Comment: I have my own answer, but it will take me some time before I can check a few things.  I suppose if I can't get the question reopened at that time, I can abuse policy and post the answer in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not one of the documented forms for `Contours`. You probably want either `Contours -> {0.}` or something like `Contours -> {{0., Red}}`.

Right now `ContourPlot3D` is trying to use the latter form, but is filling in `Automatic` for the missing style.

Answer (score 5):

The only reason I know for writing the `Contours` option nested two-deep in a list is to designate the color of the contour.

```
ContourPlot3D[x, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, Contours -> {{0., Green}}]
```

[image: green]

In this case the your short form expression looks like

```
Short[cp[[1, 2, 1]], 3]
```

> `{{EdgeForm[], RGBColor[0., 1., 0.], GraphicsGroup[{...}]}, {}, {}, {}, {}}`

which explains where the troublesome `Automatic` is coming from.

If you don't want to designate the color, write

```
ContourPlot3D[x, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, Contours -> 0]
```

or

```
ContourPlot3D[x, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, Contours -> {0}]
```

both of which work.